# Print list to txt file without [brackets] in PYTHON

Tags: python, list, text

I am trying to take a list of names, alphabetize them and print them to a new list. Here is my code:

```
names = []
newnames = []
with open("C:/names.txt", "r") as infile:
    for row in infile.readlines():
       name = row.split()
       names.append(name)
    for x in sorted(names):
       newnames.append(x)
    print newnames
f = open("C:/newnames.txt", "w")
f.write("\n".join(str(x) for x in newnames))
f.close()
```

my problem is that it prints fine except for the brackets:

```
['Bradley']

['Harold']

['Jackson']

['Lincoln']

['Mercury']

['Shane']

['Sharon']

['Sherry']

['Xavier']

['Zoolander']
```

I want that list without the brackets or quotations in the text file

Comment: Is this in some sort of programming language? Might be handy to mention which.

Comment: what language is this? python? can you show the contents of `C:/names.txt`

Comment: What language are you using? Is this Python? It looks like Python. I think it's Python. It's Python.

Comment: Its Python and the contents of C:/names is the list mentioned in the question only in a different order and one name per line with no brackets or quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you simply need to call the element of the list. The line `name = row.split()` will split the row (which is a string) by whatever is in the parenthesis, in this case nothing. So

```
In [1]: "john".split()
Out[1]: ['john']
```

If you file is just a list of name eg:
John
Harry

Then you don't need to split the row, if you do however wish to then simply indexing the 0th element:

```
row.split()[0]
```

will give you what is in the list as opposed to the list.

Answer (score 0):

`row.split` returns a list, so names contains lists. Use `extend` instead:

```
names.extend(row.split())
```